# Splitting an MS Access database--only Tables in Back End?

Tags: ms-access, split

So, I'm building this brand-new project in MS Access (2007, but I don't think it matters), and I'm getting close to the point where it's time to split the database for final testing & deployment. The ususal description of a split setup is "All tables in BE, everything else in FE", but I'm wondering if there might not be some appropriate exceptions to that:

1. I plan to keep one table of application-management data in the FE. This is one row with information such as version numbers and the application title. It would be hidden from the users.
2. While following up on the Related Questions, I saw the idea of a small startup form in the BE that tells users (nicely) to go away & open the FE instead.
3. It seems to me that *some* of my queries would actually belong in the BE instead. These particular queries are, in usage, similar to Views in SQL Server--that is, they draw together normalized data into a more denormalized presentation, and/or do a "first cut" filter on some data that's all stored together but really has one significant difference. An example of the latter is a Personnel table, with a BE query that presents a subset that are all in the same Department for further manipulation in a form (or FE query) that is *only* concerned with members of that department.

Do these sound like reasonable practices, or should I jsut stick to the "All tables/everything else" division?

Comment: I can't see any advantage in having the queries in the back-end, but the small front-end table and back-end form sound good.

Comment: The time to split is the day you start building the application. This is really not something you want to leave until the end, as there are a number issues that might show up in a split app that wouldn't be an issue in the unsplit version. Your development environment should be as close as possible to the deployment environment or you could make lots of mistakes that you'll have to address as soon as you split for deployment.

Comment: I also use the table in the FE with local settings, but I have a settings table in the BE too. At startup, I compare version numbers to check if my FE and BE versions are compatible (user might have a copy of a too old FE).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no performance to be gained by putting your "views" in the back end. The only QueryDefs that should be stored there are the ones you use when doing schema work. For instance, in all my replicated apps, I keep a handful of queries that display data from the replication system tables. None of those are relevant to the front ends.

In other words, anything that's part of the application belongs in the front end. From Jet/ACE's point of view, there really wouldn't be any difference in terms of performance, but you'd have a lot more work to utilize those back end "views" -- you can't link to them as a table like you can with a view from an ODBC data source.

Comment: I've accepted this answer for pointing out, as the others did not, that I can't link to the QueryDefs. I've upvoted all of you who answered so far, though.

Answer (score 3):

Those seem like reasonable practices, with the possible exception of #3.  The whole point of splitting an Access DB into front-end/back-end is to allow you to take the front-end off somewhere else and work on it and then replace the version the users are accessing, without replacing their data.  Anything you do that doesn't interfere with that "prime directive" should be just fine.  Of course, if you want to change the back-end schema, the back-end/front-end distinction doesn't help you, but that's what you get when you're dealing with Access, right?

The possible issue with #3 is that you're effectively lumping any changes you might need to make to the back-end queries in with schema changes.  In other words, if you need to change those queries in any way, you need to take the back-end database offline, just like you would need to do if you were changing the schema.  If you're confident that's OK, then it's not a problem, but you should be aware that you're limiting yourself in that way.  How much of a limitation it is really depends on what goes into those back-end queries.  If they're the sort of thing that you should never need to change unless the underlying schema is also changing, then you should be fine.  But if they're the sort of thing that might need to change because a user has changed their mind about how they want that data presented, then you'll be in a bit more trouble.

Comment: I'm about 98% confident that "they're the sort of thing that you should never need to change unless the underlying schema is also changing"--but if there isn't any advantage to it, as there is with creating Views in SS, then there isn't really any point.

Comment: Ken's answer is great.  In addition I always have a local settings table that stays with the FE.  When I update the FE that table gets imported.  Sometimes queries in the FE can be slow if you are joining large amounts of data.  I wrote a fn called GetSetting.  e.g. a user opens a form and chooses an invoice.  InvoiceID writes to settings table.  No form filters, the dataset is limited by the InvoiceID setting "WHERE InvoiceID=GetSetting("InvoiceID")" When the user comes back to the form later, the same Invoice they last viewed is there waiting for them. HTH

Answer (score 1):

Point 1: great. The version table, is indeed, part of the app, and not the BE. You could also compare that information in the FE to a matching version in the BE, to make sure everybody upgrades when required.

Point 2: excellent. Kick them out of the back-end. And don't forget to disable the bypass key.

Point 3: I would say no, never. The BE is (a) your tables (b) the relationships. Just think that anything else will cause trouble if you need to change it while the app is in prod. It is really different from a client server approach where everything you merge and filter in the backend is a sure performance improvement, and where you can easily change a view while the app is being used (ok I know some will react on this, but it works just fine as long as you are carefull :)

Comment: I disagree with #1 being useful as noted in my posting.

Comment: Tony: SOME tables definitely belong to the FE, like the ChangeLog or any Switchboard-like table. You CANNOT have those in the BE, since they are specific to a given version of the FE. I would also include in that category any table containing information that allows the FE to check its version is matching the version of the BE. So, I definitely keep my position here.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**  The first two paragraphs answered the wrong question as I misread point #1 and thought they meant user specific data.  On rereading the original question I do agree with #1 regarding application specific data.

I disagree with #1 and keeping any local settings in the FE.   There is no advantage to keeping a local table vs a table with the network user ID as a unique index in the BE database file.    The idea is that replacing the FE database file when you make changes should be absolutely as easy as possible.   Having to import settings every time there is a new version of the FE is simple some more work.  Yes, you can create queries and code to do the work but why even bother.

That said I only ever kept one setting locally and that was the location of the backend database file.  For that I used an INI file and API calls.  I could've used a registry key or something else.  Now when I'm doing custom work for clients on their network then this isn't really required.   This was more for shrink wrap software which folks could download from my website.   Which had my datasbase location in the linked tables connect string.

I agree with #2 because that's what I do.

As David as stated #3 shouldn't be done because it doesn't do you any good.  You need those queries in the FE where you will be using them

Comment: Tony, I think you're wrong here. While I can see storing user-related data in a back-end table keyed on the username, I can't see any point in storing version-related data in the back end. For instance, I use a "report switchboard" table for driving a form where you can open all reports. That has to be in the front end, as it has to be coordinated with the reports that are available in a particular version of the front end. Putting in the back end would vastly increase the complexity and with no particular enhancement to usability or manageability.

Comment: I'm embarrased.   I didn't read the first point clearly.   I thought he was mentioning a user specific set of data.   Not an application specific set of data.

Comment: But it *is* a good point about user-specific data--so I upvoted anyway. Thanks!

Comment: David, I've edited my answer accordingly.  Roland thanks for the comment.  I don't feel quite so foolish nmow.  <smile>

Answer (score 0):

I think the gimmik should be changed to "All data in the BE, everything else in the FE". Your front end might need to hold some tables that are not part of your "Database Model", but belong to what I should call your "Front End Metamodel":

- A simple example could be a multilingual interface where all text and caption properties can be displayed in different languages. In this situation, you could have a local\FE table that would hold all references to caption and text properties used in your application.
- Another example is when your application menus are held in a specific table, used as a source for generating form-specific menus/commandbars at runtime. Such a table should also be in your FE.
- A "connections" table, holding the different connection strings to similar databases (such as accounting databases, or different subscribers to the same publisher) should also be on your FE.

Instead of having your Front End metamodel held via tables embedded in your FE mdb file, you can also choose to hold these tables as xml files. They are at first distributed altogether with your app. It is then possible to distribute new versions of these tables (available connections, updated translations, etc) without distributing a complete FE file.

Following this logic, query/view definitions are definitely part of the FE metamodel, and holding all these views in a simple local XML or embedded Tbl_View table (2 fields only: View name and View syntax) does the trick.

Comment: So what would you use to read the local XML data files?    Why would you put queries in XML or a table?  That' a lot of extra work.

Comment: You can open these local xml files as recordsets. It can be done at startup, with 3 lines of code per recordset. It's not that extra work, isn't it?

Comment: Back to the queries, we have used this technique for years. It is very interesting to have a centralized definition of queries when these are used multiple times in the app, such as the ones used to populate combo boxes on forms. For example, in an accounting app, you will permanently refer to "Account" combo boxes or "Currency" combo boxes. In our apps, these are defined once, in this  "Query" table, which contain the combo box name and the row source definition....

Comment: ... Deciding to put it either on the FE or BE of the app is not really important, but, as we consider that they are linked to "the way data is displayed", having them on the client's side sounds more logical.

Comment: While I agree with the basic point in this answer, I think the localization answer is ill-chosen. I'd want my application MDB/ACCDB to be as independent of localization issues as possible, and have it run against some source for that information (such as localized message strings) that was outside the front end. It's perfectly possible to have a front end application divided into multiple files, so you could have your main front end and a data file with the localized text strings in it that lives in the same folder as the front end, for instance.

Comment: Whether or not I agree, I don't think this deserves a downvote--it's thoughtful & well-reasoned. Upvoted to balance.