# Place specific code in FE or BE of split MS Access database

Tags: ms-access, split, ms-access-2007

A while back I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696485/splitting-an-ms-access-database-only-tables-in-back-end/4697318#4697318) about splitting an MS Access application, and possibly leaving some of the non-table functionality in the BE. Well, I'm at it again... :)

Some of my tables will be such that they are *never* updated by the user. The data feed to these tables will be a fairly intensive code process, run daily, that extracts from Oracle, majorly massages the data & then writes to my tables (very different structure from Oracle).. There's no practical way to make it a live link to Oracle. All of the code for this will be in Modules/Class Modules, none in Forms. It absolutely would need to be changed if the schema of either the Access file or the Oracle server changes.

Given the foregoing, FE or BE?

Comment: You may want to put these tables in their own file and compact after each update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would put the code modules in a FE so that you can re-link a copy of the FE to a testing/development BE as the need arises.  The code FE needn't be the same application FE you distribute to your users.

Comment: Good point about test. My brain keeps trying to treat things like this in a similar manner to Stored Procedures, even though I know they're not....

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that I'm understanding your description -- from what I get it sounds like a temp table, i.e., with data that is replaced with something else on a regular basis. In that case, you certainly don't want it either in your front end or in your back end (if the back end is a Jet/ACE database). If that's what you have here, this data belongs in a separate back end.

For managing links to multiple back ends, you might find [my Reconnect Utility](http://dfenton.com/DFA/download/Access/Reconnect.html) useful. Since all of my apps have a temp database that's part of the front end, all of them need the ability to easy reconnect to more than one back end (the linked table manager is a real pain for that). Some of my apps have as many as four different target databases that the linked tables point at, and it's much easier to do that with my utility. It only works with Jet/ACE back ends, though (I've sketched out handling of other data sources, but never finished it, because I never needed it in any of my own applications!).

Comment: It's not a temp table. The Oracle db holds versioning data in the form of timed messages that say "This is my status". I'm massaging it into a series of "This is when the version changed" rows, with persistent history.

Comment: But the massaged data that results sounds like a temp table, even though it's based on persistent Oracle data.